# How to extract user from url in flask request?

Tags: flask, werkzeug

I just need to extract `user` in `url` i.e. `https://user@host:port/path`

From flask docs I have already try

- `request.environ`
- `request.headers`
- `request.host_url`
  ... others apis containing url word.

but not found things I need above

Thank for helping in advances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `user@` syntax in a URL, you're using HTTP authentication. Werkzeug will make the username and password from HTTP authentication available as attributes of [`request.authorization`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.14/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.AuthorizationMixin.authorization).

Comment: still not work for `request.authorization`. It might be used with form as the docs say `The Authorization object in parsed form.`

Comment: That means the contents of it have been parsed already, not that it has anything to do with HTML forms.

Comment: ok I already understand it and you are right. I must return Response object with Headers `WWW-Authenticate: Basic` to inform the incoming request must be parsed user/pass into `auhorization`. Thanks you